# Firebase - How do I set up the rules so that only Functions can write to the Realtime Databse?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a piece of Python code that writes to the realtime database.

```
def store_data(document_id, data):
  from firebase import firebase
  firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication(DB_URL, None)  
  #check for duplicate
  result = firebase.post(document_id,data)
```

I have a Cloud Scheduler job that invokes this function. I want to write the database rule so that only the Function can write to the database. What would be the best way to do that?

I have tried the following, but didn't work :

```
".write": "auth.uid === 'uid for the admin account'"
```

What would be the simplest way to only allow Firebase Functions to write to the database?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In a trusted context like a Cloud Function, you should be using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python) for Firebase, not the client SDK. The Admin SDK bypasses rules entirely, so you can write your rules as:

```
".write": false
```

and you'll still be able to use the Admin SDK.